# C# Loop, SQL and retrieving infos

Tags: c#, sql, database, loops

I have only 1 file in my database, from the group 2 and when I try to retrieve the 5 last files of this group number 2 I retrieve this file 4 times ?

I know it's a problem in my loop, but I can't see where is the problem of retrieving 4 times the same file with the same ID .

This is the code I use !

```
                dynamic queryString = ("SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] FROM Files,Groups WHERE Files.[Group] = " + param + "ORDER BY Files.Id DESC");
                SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, dbConnection);
                dbConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();

                int i = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    i++;

                    HyperLink fileHl = new HyperLink();
                    fileHl.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    fileHl.CssClass = "filelink" + i;
                    fileHl.ID = reader["Id"].ToString();
                    fileHl.NavigateUrl = String.Format("downloading.aspx?path={0}&file={1}", reader["Path"], reader["Name"]);
                    linktofiles.Controls.Add(fileHl);
                    linktofiles.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                }
```

Comment: Why are you including `Groups` table in your query if you don't use any field of it?

Comment: you are doing an odd, unqualified, join here... that usually explains most duplicates.

Comment: @Shai: I believe that is the wrong answer. In fact, fixing a broken select with a distinct is a classic mistake.

Comment: To be explicit with @Marco's comment: removing the `,Groups` will probably fix this

Comment: btw; `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are `IDisposable` - should have a few `using` statements in the above

Comment: why is your queryString dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Groups` table from your select. You are not using it, and you are not joining correctly, so it will give you unwanted results. Furthermore, don't use `dynamic` as the type for your connection string. Use `string`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your query (and not your loop):

```
"SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] 
FROM Files,Groups 
WHERE Files.[Group] = " + param + 
"ORDER BY Files.Id DESC";
```

You need a join between `Files` and `Groups` otherwise you are performing a `CROSS JOIN` and will receive a row for every matching row in `Files` times the rows in `Groups`.

In fact, you should simply remove `Groups`, since you are not selecting anything from that table:

```
"SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] 
FROM Files
WHERE Files.[Group] = " + param + 
"ORDER BY Files.Id DESC";
```

For completeness, use Parameters rather than concatenating text. Helps to avoids SQL Injection.

Comment: FTLOG can people stop posting SQL which is susceptible to SQL injection. Parameters, people; use parameters.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what SQL Injection is and can do. If I had a dollar for each time I've written "be mindful of sql injection" I'd have $50 !  I suggest you leave that comment in the right place, which is against the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic queryString = ("SELECT DISTINCT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] FROM Files,Groups WHERE Files.[Group] = " + param + "ORDER BY Files.Id DESC");`

Comment: this will probably work, but for the wrong reason; it will *work* by removing the duplicates that were added by an unnecessary full outer join. The correct approach should be: removing the incorrect join. It will, however, destroy any **genuine** duplicates in the data.